# How to start a timer without any action performed?(java swing timer)

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm reviewing for the final exam, and here is a practice problem that asking me to make a shape visible for half a second then invisible for half a second. I'm thinking of using timer in order to proceed this blinking behavior.

```
Timer count = new Timer(500, someAction)
```

but this kind of timer will need an ActionListener and an ActionPerformed in order to make this timer start.

Is there anyway I can start a timer without any actions?

Comment: `Timer` sounds like a good idea, but why wouldn't you want to use the `ActionListener` ? The `Timer` needs a callback function to trigger when it reaches the predefined time

Comment: The timer generates an action event; you change the shape visibility in the `actionPerformed()` method. No user actions are necessary.

Comment: @Robin well, i want this shape starts to blink as soon as i paint the component. so i dont want any mouse or key actions.

Comment: The timer does not need mouse nor keyboard actions. You just start the timer and it will trigger the `ActionListener` you attached to it

Comment: I guess that he's wondering *where* he shall start the timer. If he puts the start into the paint of the shape, it will be started over and over again, won't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I still think the `Timer` solution is perfect

```
Timer timer = new Timer( 500, new ActionListener(){
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ){
    //toggle visible flag of the shape
    //trigger a repaint
  }
} );
timer.setRepeats( true );
timer.start();
```

Note that you can safely adjust the visible flag of the shape (which will be used during the paint) as the `Timer` will call the `ActionListener` on the EDT. One of the main benefits of the `javax.swing.Timer`, perfect to use in combination with Swing components :-)